# Why console.log() bypasses addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, console.log

I have a button which on click is supposed to execute the addEventListener function. On the callback function part I directly use a console.log.

```
<button id="btnTrans">Translate</button>
var buttonTranslate = document.querySelector("#btnTrans");
buttonTranslate.addEventListener("click", console.log("clicked"));
```

as soon as the DOM loads, `"clicked"` appears on the console. Shouldn't it wait for the event to happen first?

Comment: It should be `buttonTranslate.addEventListener("click", e=>console.log("clicked"));`

Comment: You’re not attaching handler, Actually you called the console.log().

Comment: You're calling `console.log(...)`, then attempting to attach the *result* of that call as an event handler.

Answer (score 1):

The console.log is immediately executed because it is not wrapped in a function. Wrap it in a function:

```
buttonTranslate.addEventListener("click", () => { console.log("clicked") });
```